# Win32 api problems

Tags: winapi

Nearly everything I use related to the windows.h file doesn't work. I have included the file, yet nothing is working.

The errors that it is giving me are:
C3861: '~~': identifier not found

I have included the windows header file and scanned around on Google for awhile without finding a fix.

Comment: Can you show the actual error message?

Comment: @user3121144 I'd suggest reinstalling your compiler. It sounds like something might've gotten trashed. Your code builds cleanly for me with minor modifications (putting the code in a `main` function and declaring `msg`). You might also try looking in your `windows.h` file to see if you can spot any apparent problems, but unless `windows.h` itself is corrupted that'll be a lengthy trip down a rabbit hole of headers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you `#include <Windows.h>`?  If the compiler is telling you that PeekMessage is undefined, you're probably missing a header file.